# Bind jQuery handler to fields those created on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding some inputs on the fly using `.before()` method:

```
$("#mfrmStartPoint").before("<input type='button' class='uk-gb uk-button 
uk-button-small' value='" + $("#mfrmMaterialName").val() + "' />");
```

And I've bound .`click` method to all elements those have `.uk-gb` class, the problem is that the declared `.click` does not work for newly created elements.

```
$(".uk-gb").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("uk-active-custom")) {
        $(this).removeClass("uk-active-custom");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("uk-active-custom");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .on() method which will be bindable to dynamic elements as well.

```
$("body").on("click",".uk-gb",function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("uk-active-custom")) {
        $(this).removeClass("uk-active-custom");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("uk-active-custom");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically created elements.

```
$("#mfrmStartPoint").on("click",".uk-gb",function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("uk-active-custom")) {
        $(this).removeClass("uk-active-custom");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("uk-active-custom");
    }
});
```

In this case, event delegation helps to bind click event to your newly added input elements

Also note that, for delegated event handling it is more efficient to bind them to the closest parent that is not dynamic which is element with id `#mfrmStartPoint` in your case.